# Can't deploy Docker image to Kubernetes with Jenkins if there's no change to deployment.yml

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes, devops, gitops

I have a repo including a Dockerfile, and a github trigger, which triggers everytime there's a commit pushed to a branch. Whenever I commit any change, it creates a new docker image with tags: branch name and git hash (yes, both of them) and pushes it to registry. In my workloads, the image is described as image:branch_name. If I manually redeploy, it pulls the latest image and it works all fine. But the problem arises when I do it with Jenkins. Cause, in deployment.yml, image is imagename:branch_name, which is static all the time.

Now, I've configured a jenkins job to do `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml`. However, this doesn't pull the latest image everytime, since there's no change to yml file (image and branch name are same). How can I make Kubernetes to pull latest image everytime?

One idea I have is to pass the githash to deployment.yml so that there's a change pushed into the file, triggers the deployment. How can I achieve this?

PS: I already know `kubectl rolling-restart` and `kubectl apply`. I want to use above mentioned method. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it with kubectl patch

```
kubectl patch deployment <deployment name> -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"build\":\"${BUILD_ID}\"}}}}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the image of the deployment, it will automatically trigger a rollout.
As you tag the image with the git hash - which is good - you can then run something like this at the end of the build:

`kubectl set image deployment/my-deployment container_name=myimage:buildhash`

Comment: Is there any way to do it from inside the deployment.yml file and in jenkins just kubectl apply?
Or pass the githas to deployment.yml?

Comment: You can call `kubectl set image` right from the Jenkinsfile - that is the point when you know the image hash name anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `imagePullPolcy` to `Always` and it will always pull the latest image, or if that's insufficient there's always [Flux](https://toolkit.fluxcd.io/) which can watch your repository and update your manifests according to rules you specify (highest number, semantic versioning rules, etc).